# Getting SQL command not properly ended when creating a db2 sequence

Tags: db2

I'm trying to run some DB2 SQL from a tutorial and I keep getting "SQL command not properly ended" for this SQL:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mdm_robins80.V_ELATTR_ID_SEQ AS INT START WITH 1000000 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1000000 MAXVALUE 1009999 CACHE 10;
```

I can't see anything wrong with this statement.

Comment: What client software do you use to run your statements? What statement terminator is in effect? "SQL command not properly ended" is an Oracle error message, not DB2, by the way.